# Results of df.show() for calculated variable always returning UNDEFINED, Even when there is data in the field

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a CSV file with the following structure and Schema.

```
Age|gender|empl|weight1|WaveMarker
_35_44|_2|_1|1.836806276249|2018_7
_25_34|_1|_1|1.07306705429563|2018_7
_25_34|_1|_1|1.07306705429563|2018_7

StructType(
    StructField(Age,StringType,true), 
    StructField(gender,StringType,true), 
    StructField(empl,StringType,true), 
    StructField(weight1,DoubleType,true), 
    StructField(WaveMarker,StringType,false)
)
```

However, when reading form the CSV file all values for WaveMarker set to Undefined
Results of df.show()

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------+
|S0101_AgeBreaks_2|S0102_gender|S0104_empl|            weight1|WaveMarker|
+-----------------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------+
|           _55_64|          _2|        _1|0.45218578423031397| UNDEFINED|
|           _65_70|          _1|        _3|   1.15091044127064| UNDEFINED|
|           _65_70|          _2|        _3| 0.8322074504127289| UNDEFINED|
|           _18_24|          _2|        _1|   1.01132670132912| UNDEFINED|
|           _65_70|          _1|        _3|  0.881507097796274| UNDEFINED|
+-----------------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

The Only thing "different" about WaveMarker is that it is a calculated variable of type string.

```
//Run from Spark-shell
    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").option("mode","dropmalformed").option("maxcolumns",10000).option("inferschema","true").load("BigFile.csv")

df.show()
```

I expect to see a value other than Undefined for WaveMarker for all cases.

However all values of WaveMarker are undefined.

Why can't I get the value of WaveMarker?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I need to read my own code.  A reused function is clobbering WaveMarker.

Comment: To quote Emily Litella, Nevermind.